# Python DEAP: Fitness seems to go down over time - how do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, deap

My individual is a concatenation of the five parameters needed to tweak a multi-stage process. The first population is created by randomly assigning those parameters a value within their respective ranges and converting that into a binary string. A graph of the first 25 generations typically looks like this:

[image: Graph of the first 25 generations]

The DEAP code looks like this:

```
# Create the individuals
creator.create('FitnessMax', base.Fitness, weights=(1.0, ))
creator.create('Individual', list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

# Initialize the containers
toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register('individual', get_random_contour_ind)
toolbox.register('population', tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

# Initialize the operators
toolbox.register('evaluate', get_total_max_ratio)
toolbox.register('mate', tools.cxUniform, indpb=0.10)
toolbox.register('mutate', tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.10)
toolbox.register('select', tools.selBest)
```

It takes a long time to run, but I've run the same DEAP code on other evaluators and am noticing the same pattern. How do I fix this?

Comment: What algorithm are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the evaluator is non-deterministic, so I took [paddymccrudden](https://github.com/paddymccrudden)'s advice and added a decorator to enforce stochastic fitness. Now the fitness graph looks like this:

[image: 25 generations of stochastic fitness enforcement]

As you can see the average fitness is increasing over the generations.